# bootstrap collapse does not work correctly ,closes immediately after opening

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have a table tag which i want to open it when the button is clicked but it opens it but close it immediately

```
        <button class="btn btn-primary" 
         "data-toggle="collapse" 
         href="#collapseExample" 
         aria-expanded="false">Get rate</button>
```

here is my table :

```
            <table  class="table table-hover table-condensed collapse" id="collapseExample">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:50%"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">You Pay</th>
                <td>{{total}} SEK</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Price</th>

                <td>{{price}} {{currency}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row">Rate</th>
                <td colspan="2">{{rate}}</td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Comment: 1. You have an extra `"` before your `data-toggle`. 2. If removing that doesn't fix, check your imports. Is by any change, Bootstrap JS being loaded twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of  **`collapsing the table`**, just gave it to a new `div` which covers the `<table>`... To get the collapsing animation
And also there was an extra **double-quote** `"` in your button code that was also the issue

I used `data-bs-toggle="collapse"` because i used **`bootstrap 5`**,
You can use data-toggle="collapse" if you are using **`bootstrap 4`**

The below code should get you what you're looking for...

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Get rate</button>
         
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">       
            <table  class="table table-hover table-condensed  " >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th style="width:50% "></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row ">You Pay</th>
                <td>{{total}} SEK</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row ">Price</th>

                <td>{{price}} {{currency}}</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th scope="row ">Rate</th>
                <td colspan="2 ">{{rate}}</td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: This may be the answer, but adding an explanation would greatly increase the quality of your answer.  What did you do, and why do you think it will help? *Explain* your answer, so future visitors of all skill levels can learn from it.  [Code-only answers are considered low quality on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers).